# Adding/multiplying summations of different indices to prove Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: inequality, summation

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_j^2 +
\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2 \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_ja_j$

Can someone walk me through this. The different summation indices is throwing me off. 
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is generally written as

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i \le (\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2)^{1/2}.$

So I'm not 100% sure what the elements $b_j$ and $a_j$ are.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: start off by expanding the square:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2
  =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_i^2b_j^2-2a_ib_ja_jb_i+a_j^2b_i^2)$$
Now split the sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2
  =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_i^2b_j^2
    -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}2a_ib_ja_jb_i
    +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2b_i^2\ .$$
The reason this RHS equals the previous RHS is that you are adding up the same things, only in a different order.  Now for the first sum, think about what happens when $j$ varies from $1$ to $n$.  As this happens, the $a_i^2$ never changes, so it is a constant factor and can be taken out of the sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_i^2b_j^2
  =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_i^2b_j^2\Bigr)
  =\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_j^2\Bigr)\ .$$
And now the sum over $j$ adds up to a fixed quantity which does not depend on $i$, so it can be taken outside the sum over $i$ to give
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_i^2b_j^2
  =\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_j^2\Bigr)\ .$$

The last two steps are really just the same as
$$\sum_{j=1}^3ab_j=ab_1+ab_2+ab_3=a(b_1+b_2+b_3)=a\sum_{j=1}^3b_j\ .$$

Hopefully you can now treat the rest of the original expression in the same way.  Good luck!

Comment: So how do I get from $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_j^2 +
\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2 \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_ja_j$ to $2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2) - 2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i)^2$ @David

Comment: What do you get if you write out $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_j^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2 \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2$ in full, without using summation signs?

Comment: $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... + a_n^2 \times b_1^2 + b_2^2 +...+ b_n^2$ and $b_1^2 + b_2^2 + ... + b_n^2 \times a_1^2 + a_2^2 +...+ a_n^2$ ??

Comment: Okay so I see how the right hand side is reduced. $(-2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i)^2$ but I'm not quite seeing the left hand side @David

Comment: You need brackets in your previous comment: $(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)(b_1^2+\cdots+b_n^2)$ and $(b_1^2+\cdots+b_n^2)(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)$.  Now what do you notice about these two expressions?

Comment: And take the original left hand side $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2$.  Can you tell if this is positive or negative?

Comment: I see it now, thanks for your time. @david